# Python: Compare two CSV using Panda (isin) which are un-equal in length and columns are also different except one common column & also get matching %

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to compare two csv here which looks like this
*csv1.csv*

| Id | Km1 |
| --- | --- |
| A01 | 2.20 |
| A02 | 1.10 |
| A03 | 1.05 |
| A04 | 0.50 |

*csv2.csv*

| T_Id | ID | Km2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AB01 | A011 | 1.0 |
| AB02 | A02 | 1.0 |
| AB03 | A03 | 0.75 |
| AB04 | A05 | 0.550 |
| AB05 | A04 | 1.10 |
| AB06 | A012 | 1.0 |
| AB07 | A020 | 0.70 |

- I am looking to compare data and then build csv which has common Ids from both csv and all other columns associated with that
- Also, is it possible to do sorting on data either on Km1 and Km2 with sort function?
- Is there efficient way to compare this data using anything other than pandas?
- Can we also get matching % from these based on total number of Ids from both csv?

| T_Id | ID | Km1 | Km2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AB02 | A02 | 1.10 | 1.0 |
| AB03 | A03 | 1.05 | 0.75 |
| AB04 | A04 | 0.50 | 1.10 |

This is my sample code

```
import pandas as pd
def pnd_check():
    df1 = pd.read_csv("csv1.csv")
    print("Total records:",len(df1))

    df2 = pd.read_csv("csv2.csv")
    print("Total recors:",len(df2))

    matching_result1 = df1[df1['Id'].isin(df2['Id'])]
    matching_result2 = df2[df2['Id'].isin(df1['Id'])]
    print (matching_result1, matching_result1)
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: How would you want to calculate matching percentage?
Because you have df1 and df2, against which one you would like to compare matching percentage?

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/2631229/aidis Maybe in separate function we could store total Ids and compare them with matched ids from the merged list? Ex. 8 unique ids from the both csv and 3 matched so 37.5% is avg. something like that I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Merging

```
df.merge(df1, on="ID")
```

Result:

```
    ID  Km2_x  T_Id  Km2_y
0  A02   1.10  AB02   1.00
1  A03   1.05  AB03   0.75
2  A04   0.50  AB05   1.10
```

### Sorting

```
In [8]: merged = df.merge(df1, on="ID")

In [9]: merged.sort_values(by="Km2_y")
Out[9]:
    ID  Km2_x  T_Id  Km2_y
1  A03   1.05  AB03   0.75
0  A02   1.10  AB02   1.00
2  A04   0.50  AB05   1.10
```

### Calculating percentage of matching

```
merged.shape[0] / pd.concat([df['ID'], df1['ID']]).nunique()
```

0.35

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/2631229/aidis Wow.. That was superb. Not sure why I got stuck into 'isin'. Okay, one more on this.. can we rename the Km2_y and Km2_x?

Comment: You can rename with `merged.rename(columns={"Km2_x":"name", "Km2_y":"name2"})`